# Is it wise to use sprites to improve manageability of static, retina graphics in a non-gaming app?

Tags: ios, user-interface, graphics, workflow, sprite

As my app's UI grows in complexity, I'm finding it tedious exporting all the graphics for things like buttons. For instance with toggle buttons: up, down, disabled, on, off * 5 buttons * 2 for retina = 50 graphics which need exporting!  Is it a viable strategy to do as one does in CSS and make a sprite sheet?  If so, might you point me in the direction of a snippet or two on how to handle loading and displaying the appropriate subsection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sprite sheet, and a way to do that is here:
http://www.danielsefton.com/2012/07/texture-atlases-for-uikit-with-texturepacker/

As an alternative to sprite sheets, PaintCode is a great option from the Mac App Store.  It makes it very easy to update graphics, simply copy and paste code.  Unfortunately it's relatively high-priced.

If you need to create images that Paint Code can't handle, consider using a Mac app to automatically duplicate & resize the artwork, this way you only have to create it once.  There are several on the Mac App Store.  Some are free and others are paid.  But if you want high quality resizing, it's best to use the tool you made the art with to do the downsizing (such as PhotoShop).

Comment: Thx.  Just what I wanted.  Now if there was only a way to get IB to use the sprite images...

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that, unfortunately.